# Share on whats app both App Store and Play store links

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using the following code to share to share some text through UIActivityViewController.

```
NSString *appUrlAppStore = @"https://itunes.apple.com/app/imdb-movies-tv/id342792525";
NSString *appUrlPlayStore = @"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imdb.mobile";
NSString *textToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey, this is an Awesome app and you can get this from App Store : %@  Play Store : %@", appUrlAppStore ,appUrlPlayStore];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[textToShare] applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]; 

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now the problem is that which ever link is first (like in the above App Store one) whats app takes the thumbnail of that link

What i want is that if the device is an ios one it should pick the appStore one and of its Android it should pick the play store one.

I do get it that this is the default behavior of WhatsApp but what would be the solution for my problem. Or if most app do behave like this than I guess my users won’t mind as well.

or is there any key thing that i am missing.

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Use can use branch.io to generate one link for iOS and android also your can track links. Branch.io also provide Analytics and its free.

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre many thanks, this would definitely solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use [branch.io](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/) to generate one link for iOS and android also can track links. Branch.io provides deep links with referral systems, sharing links, invites and marketing links with full attribution and analytics. You can refer [branch.io](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/) for SDK integration or for more simple you can refer [branch.io Git repo](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking) for integration.

Replace your UIActivityViewController with this code.

```
BranchUniversalObject *branchUniversalObject = [[BranchUniversalObject alloc] initWithCanonicalIdentifier:@"user_id"];
branchUniversalObject.title = @"Hey, this is an Awesome app and you can get this from App Store";
branchUniversalObject.contentDescription =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",@"Your friend",user_name,@"has invited you to  download awesome App"];
branchUniversalObject.imageUrl = @"APP_Image_url";
BranchLinkProperties *linkProperties = [[BranchLinkProperties alloc] init];
linkProperties.feature = @"share";
linkProperties.channel = @"WhatsApp";
[branchUniversalObject showShareSheetWithLinkProperties:linkProperties
                                       andShareText:@"Super amazing App I want to share!"
                                 fromViewController:self
                                        andCallback:^{
                                            NSLog(@"finished sharing link");
                                        }];
```